# Using a Breakpoint which one is to be used Mixin or Placeholder in Sass

Tags: css, sass, placeholder, mixins

I am using Mixin for the breakpoints like this

```
$breakpoints: ( 'tiny': ( max-width: 480px ), 'small': ( max-width: 767px ), 'medium': ( max-width: 992px ), 'large': ( max-width: 1199px ) ); // Creating the mixin
```

and in SCSS i am calling like

```
  @include breakpoint(small) {

        }
```

My point is that i am calling this mixin at many location so the size of css in increases.

which is the best way to use breakpoints in SASS `enter code here`

Comment: "My point is that ... the size of css in increases." So? Have you proven this is a legitimate problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chek this breakpoint mixin.

```
@mixin respond-to($breakpoint) {
  @if $breakpoint == "mobile-small" {
    @media (min-width: 320px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else if $breakpoint == "mobile-big" {
    @media (min-width: 640px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else if $breakpoint == "small" {
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else if $breakpoint == "medium" {
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else if $breakpoint == "large" {
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else if $breakpoint == "ex-large" {
    @media (min-width: 1920px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

and call the mixin like this. e.g.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    @include respond-to(small) {
      width: 750px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    @include respond-to(medium) {
      width: 980px;
      padding: 0 15px;
    }
    @include respond-to(large) {
      width: 1140px;
    }
    @include respond-to(ex-large) {
      width: 1600px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. This is always mobile first as it should be and manages any and all breakpoints with ease.

```
$breakpoints: (
    "watch":        0,
    "phone-small":      320px,
    "phone-mid":        480px,
    "phone":            560px,
    "tablet-small":     640px,
    "tablet-mid":       768px,
    "tablet":           1024px,
    "desktop":          1248px,
    "desktop-large":    1440px,
    "desktop-xlarge":   2060px
);

@mixin screen-size($width, $type: min) {
    @if map_has_key($breakpoints, $width) {
        $width: map_get($breakpoints, $width);
        @if $type == max {
            $width: $width - 1px;
        }
        @media only screen and (#{$type}-width: $width) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you enjoy it.

Usage looks like this

```
@include screen-size('tablet-small') {
    /* your css */
}
```